# Relations viaTable yii2

Tags: yii2

I have 3 tables (`order`, `order_delivery`, `order_types`). Every table has model. For order I create GridView. Table `order` has column `order_number`, table `order_delivery` has `order_number` and `order_delivery_code`, table `order_type` has `delivery_types_code` and `delivery_types_name`. In Order I write function

```
public function getType() {
    return $this->hasOne(OrderDelivery::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']) 
        ->viaTable('delivery-types', ['delivery-types_code' => 'order_delivery_code']); 
}
```

In `index` I write `type.delivery-types_name` - there is

> Getting unknown property: backend\models\Order::order_delivery_code

What I do wrong?

Upd. my fault)

```
public function getType(){
    return $this->hasOne(DeliveryTypes::className(), ['delivery-types_code' => 'order_delivery_code'])
        ->viaTable('order_delivery', ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

Comment: Is your table named `delivery-types` and its column named `delivery-types_code`? With hyphens?

Comment: @Bizley in db which I use a lot of columns and table with terrible names. I'm not create this, just use it)

Comment: Yii 2 maps columns as object properties so there might be problem with column names containing characters not allowed in property name (like hyphen). Any chance to modify them in DB, or create a DB view with aliases?

Comment: @Bizley When I create model in gii for table like `order-delivery`, I have a lot of problem. I had to comment out several lines with the rules in vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\model\Generator.php. After creating model I uncomment this. I have just "select" in this db.

Comment: It's like I said, Yii 2 uses ActiveRecord pattern and that is why some column naming convention must be kept in order to work properly. If you persist on the names you have got now you can use other ORM like i.e. `Doctrine` but you have to prepare it on your own.